# CoordinatorLayout scroll handling breaks down

Tags: android

I have a CoordinatorLayout that contains a toolbar and a RecyclerView. I have configured the layout such that the toolbar shrinks and hides as the user scrolls the RecyclerView. This works fine. Unless the cells (rows) of the RecyclerView themselves contain horizontally scrolling RecyclerViews. When I tap on such a cell and scroll up the toolbar does not hide. It appears that the CoordinatorLayout handling the scroll event of these cells and somehow getting confused. Is there a way to work around the problem?

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Button 1" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/button2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Button 2" />
      </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:paddingBottom="0pt"
      android:paddingLeft="0pt"
      android:paddingRight="0pt"
      android:paddingTop="0pt"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
      </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your RecycelerView rows layout.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on SO moments after I posed this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32975317/1036017

Essentially, for any cell that contains a horizontally scrolling RecyclerView we have to disable nested scrolling. Here is an example layout for such a cell. We set the `android:nestedScrollingEnabled` property to false.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="250dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/left_chevron"
        android:id="@+id/leftArrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_chevron"
        android:id="@+id/rightArrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```